# Backgrounds on no-height divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

I keep running into this same issue over and over again - a fluid div with floated elements in it has no background (because it has "no height"). I've tried using :after selectors, , and even making up a fake height. But none of these solutions is elegant or consistent. I would like to know the best, most adaptable, most flexible method for dealing with this. I'm looking for the "this is how the pros do it" solution, that I can reuse over and over and never have to worry about it again.

Here's an extremely simple jsFiddle you can play with. The lists should have an orange background.
http://jsfiddle.net/y4Va3/

Code from the jsFiddle:

```
.wrapper {background-color: blue; width: 100%;}
.content {background-color: orange; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;}
.bottom {background-color: green; width: 100%; clear: both;}
ul {margin: 0px 10px; padding: 0; float: left;}
li {list-style-type: none;}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        Not much here
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As most have said, `overflow: hidden` is the preferred way of making sure your collapsing elements get the height that they need. Here's [a nice explanation](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/):

> The following property/value combinations will cause an element to
>   establish a new block formatting context:
>
> ```
> float: left and float: right 
> display: inline-block, display:
> inline-table, display: table-cell and display: table-caption 
> position: absolute and position: fixed 
> overflow: hidden, overflow: auto and overflow: scroll 
>   and their overflow-x and overflow-y counterparts.
> ```
>
> It's not hard to understand why overflow: hidden (or  overflow: auto)
>   is generally used for establishing a new BFC: all other options either
>   have often highly undesirable side-effects, or are unsupported by
>   Internet Explorer 7 and below.

So in theory, you could use any of the above to make sure your parent element knows it has other elements inside it (it's good to keep in mind though that all of them simply have the *side effect* of creating a new  BFC, with the purpose of the listed properties obviously being something entirely different).

A trick I use quite often if I can't add `overflow: hidden` for some reason (eg, menus showing on hover that span outside of the parent), is to float the parent element, too. In your case, like so:

```
.content {
    background-color: orange;
    width:50%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Of course, this would break your centering, and would not be suitable in this particular case. But it's nice to keep in mind in cases where you don't want to hide your overflows. You can then also add a `width: 100%` for good measure to make sure your floating parent element imitates a block-level structure :)

Comment: Selected this as the answer because it actually helps to explain why this technique works.

Answer (score 1):

**Define your** `.content` `overflow:hidden` **as like this**

```
.content {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Va3/1/)**

## =========

**Option no 2nd**

```
.content:after{content:"";
overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    display:table;
}
```

**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Va3/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this `Demo`

http://jsfiddle.net/y4Va3/2/.

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    background-color: orange;
    width:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.bottom {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
ul {
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/y4Va3/4/

hope this is what you want

```
.content {
    background-color: orange;
    width:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try overflow:auto;

```
.content {
    background-color: orange;
    width:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
  }
```

[Link-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Va3/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `height 100%, overflow hidden`

```
.content {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Va3/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this link..**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Va3/7/)**

U need to refer like this..

```
.content ul li{
    background-color:red;
}
```

hope this is wat u want...

Answer (score 1):

All you gotta do is add a clearfix

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/yECkB/

```
.clearfix {
display: block; clear:both;
```

}